# registering images with loops c#

Tags: c#, image, file, loops

I've tried

```
private void RegImages(int max)
    {
        string maxS = max.ToString();
        bool t = false;
        do
        {
            max--;
            if (max <= 0)
            {
                t = true;
            }
            Image maxS = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\MahchinLizard\Desktop\assets\tiles\" +max +".png");
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while (t == true);
    }
```

But it doesn't work, well i don't know if it should.

If there is any way to loop images, i would love to know thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use following loop:

```
        while (!t)
        {
            max--;
            if (max <= 0)
            {
                t = true;
            }
            Image maxS = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\MahchinLizard\Desktop\assets\tiles\" +max +".png");
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Comment: @MahchinLizard, are you have all images with name: "0.png", "1.png", ..., "max-1.png" in tiles folder?

Comment: yes i got "0.png", "1.png" all the way to the max that i intup in the RegImages(int max)

Comment: t is a bool registered in the function so your seeing everything.

Comment: @MahchinLizard, I'm sorry, I mean, what's value of max in loop, when program fail. And post this exception (this may be more informative for helping)